# Как убрать нижнюю рамку у table-header-group

Tags: html, css

Как можно убрать жирную нижнюю рамку у table-header-group? Похоже на то, что не действует border-collapse на нижнюю рамку, html код нельзя менять

```css
/* Используемые цвета:

#777777
#ffffff
#fffebc
#b2fdd0
#ffbaba

*/

.formula {
    display: table;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}

.formula p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

article.formula p {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
}

article.formula ul {
    display: table-row;
}

article.formula ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

article.formula .content {
    display: table-row-group;
    background-color: #b2fdd0;
}

article.formula header {
    display: table-header-group;
    border-bottom: none;
}

article.formula .content-important {
    background-color: #fffebc;
}

article.formula div[class="content"] ul li:last-of-type {
    background-color: #ffbaba;
}

div[class="column"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Испытание: строим таблицу на CSS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/assets/course86/">
        <link href="course.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <article class="formula">
            <p>Поваренная книга</p>
            <div class="column-group">
                <div class="column"></div>
                <div class="column"></div>
                <div class="column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-last"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="img/blue-crystal.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/bones.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/magic.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/stick.png" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="img/green-crystal.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/stick.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li>–</li>
                    <li><img src="img/skull.png" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <header>
                <ul>
                    <li>Объект 1</li>
                    <li>Объект 2</li>
                    <li>Объект 3</li>
                    <li>Результат</li>
                </ul>
            </header>
            <div class="content content-important">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="img/led.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/fireball.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/sand-glass.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="img/gold.png" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можете объяснить зачем вы верстаете табличный контент какими-то левыми тегами, а не используете `<table>`, который предназначен для этого?

Answer (score 0):

```
article.formula header li {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь дать более развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
    header>ul>li{border-bottom: 0 !important;}
```

проверка тут https://jsfiddle.net/ytmkuoo4/